# Java apply cartoonizer effect

Tags: java, android, image-processing, imagefilter

I want create a image filter which will create a cartoonizer effect. What I am trying is something like this -

[image: cartoonizer]

Please help with the procedure to achieve this. I need this to be done in Java.

If a working code is not possible, at least give me some idea how generally this things are done. As there is a lot of websites do this now a days, I assume this should not be too difficult.

What I have tried so far is this -

```
BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(new File(basePath + "in11.jpg"));
BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(in.getWidth(), in.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

EdgeFilter edgeFilter = new EdgeFilter();
edgeFilter.filter(in, out);

GrayscaleFilter grayscaleFilter = new GrayscaleFilter();
grayscaleFilter.filter(out, out);

InvertFilter invertFilter = new InvertFilter();
invertFilter.filter(out, out);
```

But this is a code for create a sketch effect (I am using JHLabs Filters from this [link](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html) ). Output is this -

[image: output-sketch]

Now my assumption is if I able to implement a filter which will decrease the number of colours in my image and then if I overlay it with the sketch image I might get my desire effect. But I don't know hot to implement that.

Answer (score 3):

- repaint object using palette with small amount of color (k-means method is suitable to find which colors to use, but you should determine a number of colors)
- optional: use morphological operations to filter noise (dilation + erosion)
- find edges (Canny etc)
- simplify edges using any of contour simplification algorithm

Another way is to use bilateral smoothing filter on its extreme paramters (smooth very much): [see example and code](https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=73648&lngWId=1).

OpenCV lib is ok for this, it also supports Java, or you can use JavaCV as Java-openCV proxy.

Comment: Hi Vit, thanks for your reply. but can you please explain in more details. i am not able to get all of them clearly.

Comment: Detailed explanation will take pages, but it is not worth it since it is well described everywhere. Terms are: k-means clustering, morphology, Canny edge detection, contour simplification. For instance after palette reducing by http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/07/color-quantization-opencv-using-k-means-clustering/ you can find simplified contours by using http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours.

Comment: Hi Vit, thanks. i will try. could you please refer me a book or tutorial on image processing for novices. i feel like i should know this terms in little details. it might help me in my other projects.

Comment: I never read books, only articles and docs. Try this http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html